# Deluge keeps crashing

Tags: 12.04, bittorrent, deluge

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 for almost a week now and tried Deluge 1.3.6 (through the ppa their website provided), but it keeps crashing. I don't really know why it does though. I had searched the internet for more information on it, but couldn't find the reason nor a solution. I tried deluge 1.3.5 without the ppa, which crashed also.

I noticed that the versions of libtorrent differ when asking deluge or the package manager.

```
user@pc:~$ deluge -v
deluge: 1.3.6
libtorrent: 0.15.10.0
```

While it says 0.15.10-1 in the package manager after libtorrent-rasterbar6. Not sure if this is related to the problem though.

Since the crash report is quite large, I didn't really know what information to provide, but I read deluge was supposedly be a good torrent client for Ubuntu, so what do you think the problem is and what can I do to fix this?

**@Rinzwind:** The warning is when starting Deluge, the segmentation fault is when it crashes.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/mainwindow.py:108: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  gtk.main_iteration(False)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Update**
After updating to 0.16.14.0 as mentioned in Cas's answer, the warning remains, though it hasn't crashed yet. I'll update if it crashes again.

Comment: Start it from command line and post the error messages.

Comment: @Rinzwind Error messages added.

Comment: FYI: Any GTK warnings are irrelevant to the crash and can be ignored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a known libcrypto issue with 0.15 libtorrent on 12.04 so you can use 0.16 libtorrent from the [Deluge PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deluge-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=precise)